# Directions between points on map?

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, google-maps-api-2, direction

I need any help in finding directions between path point

the problem is i can find bearing, distance and angles between points this page helped me a lot i have the latitude and longitude of each point on the route

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

but i want to know how to tell user to turn "left" or turn "right" using these equations if anyone used same functionality in any language just tell me

Comment: If this is not answered in two days I'll start a bounty on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 0 degrees is going forward, 180 degrees is going backward, and the angles go clockwise from 0 to 360 degrees.

```
340 - 20:  Continue forward
20 - 60:   Turn slightly right    
60 - 120:  Turn right
120 - 160: Turn sharply right
160 - 200: Turn around
200 - 240: Turn sharply left
240 - 300: Turn left
300 - 340: Turn slightly left
```